# How to understand "whether or not" here if there are no two clauses in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Neo learns that Zion will be destroyed:

> Neo: You won't let it happen. You can't. You need human beings to
> survive.
>
> The Architect: There are levels of survival we are prepared to accept.
> The relevant issue is **whether or not** you are ready...to accept the
> responsibility for  the death of every human being in this world.

How to understand "whether or not" here if there are no two clauses in the sentence?

Comment: "Whether or not you are ready ..." is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) so, yes, there are two clauses in that sentence. The meaning is "The relevant issue is the answer to the question 'Are you ready or not to accept ... ?'"

Comment: @BillJ Is there any problem to convert that comment into answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *There are levels of survival we are prepared to accept. The relevant*
> *issue is* [*whether or not you are ready ... to accept the responsibility*
> *for the death of every human being in this world*].

"Whether or not you are ready the responsibility ..." is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) so, yes, there are two clauses in that sentence.

The meaning is "The relevant issue is the answer to the question 'Are you ready or not to accept the responsibility for ... ?'"

Note that there is a further embedded subordinate clause, i.e. the infinitival "to accept the responsibility for the death of every human being in this world", which is functioning as complement of "ready".