# How to understand "even if" here if there are no two clauses in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), The Architect says to Neo about Oracle:

> The Architect: As I was saying, she stumbled upon a solution whereby 99 percent of subjects... ...accepted the program, as long as they
> were given a choice...**even if** they were only aware of the choice
> at a near unconscious level.

How to understand "even if" here if there are no two clauses in the sentence?

Comment: Please clarify what it is you don't understand. What has the number of clauses to do with it? _Even if_ introduces a subordinate clause, so there are two clauses.

Comment: I count five clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Architect: As I was saying, she stumbled upon a solution whereby 99 percent of subjects... ...accepted the program, as long as they were given a choice...even if they were only aware of the choice at a near unconscious level.

There is more than one clause, and I  identify them, following a similar line of reasoning used in another question in [How to understand "whether or not" here if there are no two clauses in the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/304052/how-to-understand-whether-or-not-here-if-there-are-no-two-clauses-in-the-sente)

1. *As I was saying*
2. *she stumbled upon a solution*
3. *whereby 99 percent of subjects... ...accepted the program*
4. *as long as they were given a choice...*
5. *even if they were only aware of the choice at a near unconscious level*

(2) is the main clause.

(1) is an introductory dependent adverbial clause.

(3)+(4)+(5) forms a nest of embedded subordinate clauses.

Edit

*even if* links (4) and (5).